# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro en una consulta dentro de SQL y ordenarla?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla `Emisoras`con varios campos, los que me conciernen son `Instrumento (int)` y `Serie (varchar)`;

Primero busco que despliegue el instrumento, el asunto está en que a veces son más de un registro (con el instrumento 118, por ejemplo), y quiero que **no muestre** aquellos instrumentos cuya serie empiece con los dos últimos dígitos de los años anteriores a este (2017), i. e. `16,15,14`

la consulta que intenté (y fracasó) es la siguiente:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    Emisoras 
where 
    Instrumento='N' 
    and 
    (where Serie like '17%' or '18%') 
order by 
    Serie Desc;
```

Comment: Has de añadir por qué te fracasó. Un error? resultado no esperado ?

Comment: podrias agregar un pequeño set de datos, y los datos resultados de ese set...

Comment: Si Instrumento es int, Instrumento='N' va a fallar

Comment: Suopngo que falló por que no está bien redactado el código. @Simon 'N' es un ejemplo, bien podría ser el '118'

Comment: entonces escribe 118, si vas a poner un ejemplo tiene que ser igual a lo que te esta causando problemas.

Comment: Serie siempre va a empezar con 2 numeros? Que pasa el proximo año y despues?

Comment: Serie es una fecha (aammdd) siempre así, estaría interesante que validara aquellos cuya serie sea mayor o igual a la fecha actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo asumiendo que tu año siempre sea el actual seria:

```
select *
from Emisoras
where Instrumento = 'N'
    and CAST(LEFT(Serie, 2) AS INT) >= RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()), 2)
```

O si tienes una fecha como referencia:

```
select *
from Emisoras
where Instrumento = 'N'
    and CAST(LEFT(Serie, 2) AS INT) >= RIGHT(YEAR(@TUFECHA), 2)
```

**Sustituye  @TUFECHA por la fecha que envias como parametro**

**Nota: Se asume que las series todas empiezan con los digitos del año**

**Edicion en base al comentario del OP**
Si tu serie siempre se basa en YYMMDD puedes hacer:

```
select *
from Emisoras
where Instrumento = 'N'
    and CAST(LEFT(Serie, 6) AS DATE) >= GETDATE()
```

> CAST(LEFT(Serie, 6) AS DATE) te transforma los 6 digitos iniciales de la serie en una fecha y la compara contra la fecha actual, si es igual o mayor los resultados son devueltos

Comment: De hecho sería mejor si en vez de sólo el año, se validara la fecha actual con formato (aammdd) que es como se contruye Serie. Es decir, si `Serie` (visto como fecha) es anterior a hoy, no se muestren esos Instrumentos. Lo de la fecha de referencia también es útil

Comment: Te dejo una forma adicional en base a tu comentario de la construccion de la serie

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto quería conseguir.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes alguas cosas demás y algunas demenos, pero casi casi :)

```
select 
    * 
from 
    Emisoras 
where 
    Instrumento='N' 
    and 
    (Serie like '17%' or Serie like '18%') 
order by 
    Serie Desc
```

Comment: Gracias buen hombre, quedó como quería. En unos minutos lo marco como respuesta porque no me deja la página.

Comment: pero si quisiera que en vez de buscar 17 y 18, quisiera que no mostrara los anteriores a éstos ¿cómo cambiaría?

Comment: Estás usando un filtro de texto, quizás quieras usar filtros de fecha para eso (mayor/menor que o `between`), eso va a depender de como esté formateada la fecha en el varchar.

Comment: Ok. Por ahora esto me resuelve bastante. Gracias.